# Where should I upload a text file for a stackoverflow post?

Tags: discussion

It seems I can't upload text file, which has relevant info regarding a question I want to ask. Is there a safe alternative I can upload to and link to (besides Github)

Answer (score 14):

Any relevant text should really be pasted directly into a post. That way there's a permanent record of the content.

Comment: But the text file has over 1000s of urls, which is needed to reproduce the example.

Comment: @Moondra So it's impossible to create an example that would reproduce it without thousands of urls?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not talented with the whole flow chart drawing thing, otherwise I'd make a fancy visual version with fun options and everything, but the basic idea is this:

Think about how much text that file contains.

-- Does it contain very little? Then post it as part of your question so that people have it readily available and can copy from it.

-- Does it contain a lot? Then think about what it contains.

If you don't have your answer yet, ask your self what does the file contain?

-- If it contains code, reduce your code to a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example, something short (Always try for less than 10 lines, this might not always be possible but the more you reduce the code, the easier it is for the people answering to sift through and find the issue). Then, incorporate the reduced code version into your question.

-- If it doesn't contain code, it might be a data file read by your program, background to the issue you're having, or program requirements. If you think of something else it might hold that has a different course of action that I'm about to describe, go ahead and comment it. In any of the cases I mentioned, any of those can be reduced to something more easily consumed by the people answering your question if they are reduced to just the necessary information. Perhaps the data file can be reduced to just a few lines to emulate the behavior you want, or the program requirements can be reduced to just the ones that affect your issue. Either way, shorten it, then include it in your question.

Remember, everyone on Stack Overflow offers their answering abilities as a service, and as an asker, it is your responsibility to make that job as simple as possible for the answerer. Nobody wants to read a huge text file just to help you out with your problem just because you cannot be bothered to simplify it.

Lastly, if there is any reason why you absolutely have to include a really long amount of text, put it in a code block so that it is scrollable. But this should **only** be done if you **cannot** reduce it to just a few relevant lines. This last idea isn't necessarily the best, since only code should go in code blocks, but comparing it to asking users to go off site or download a file or something, putting the text in a code block to make it part of your question would be better if it cannot be shortened.

Comment: I'd love to see the fancy visual version.